# Aligned heap allocation for unknown types

Tags: c++, memory, c++17, memory-alignment

Given alignment and size of an otherwise unknown type, how can one safely construct *free storage* (heap) that is properly aligned?

For context: The automatic storage version is well documented. See the example at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage: An opaque uninitialized storage on stack gets properly aligned, which can later be placement new'ed once type is known.

Is it possible to similarly do alignment-safe uninitialized allocation on the heap? This storage would later get placement-new initialized once the type is known (and deleted in type-aware context with proper destruction etc.)

The following naïve attempt fails:  https://godbolt.org/z/PM1xWoYox

What is the mental model here with heap storage?

Comment: `std::aligned_storage` is just a type. What is stopping you from allocating it on the heap instead of the stack?

Comment: Good question: (a) The sz and align are runtime values. (b) curious on how to do this properly with (sz, align) overloads of operators new and delete. For example, even when the align argument is provided as `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` the apparent behavior is incorrect when new(sz,align) is paired with typed delete (without align).

Comment: Did you try doing delete in 2 steps, since you also did new in 2 steps?

Answer (score 0):

Given the problems you are having with `new` and `delete`, you might consider using `aligned_alloc` and `free` instead.  For example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

struct Foo
{
    Foo (double d) : m_d (d) {}
    double m_d;
};

int main ()
{
    void *storage = aligned_alloc (alignof (Foo), sizeof (Foo));
    Foo* foo = new (storage) Foo (3.14);
    ...
    foo->~Foo ();
    free (storage);
}
```

Note that, to destroy an object created by placement `new`, you must call the destructor explicitly.  You don't call `delete`.  Then you must free the underlying storage.

Comment: "to destroy an object created by placement new, you must call the destructor explicitly" I suppose this is really the crux of my question, so, thanks for putting it this way.  Though, is that really the case for heap storage? Where in the standard does it say this? Even so, isn't delete supposed to call "~T()" then deallocate the storage anyway? What is the underlying model of new/delete that even when the alignment integer value is identical with the two calls (with and without std::align_val_t overloads), that this parity becomes necessary to impose?

Comment: For additional context: The primary motivation I am pursuing a cleaner solution than two-step delete, is to be able to extract, say, a `std::unique_ptr<T>` out of an uninitialized storage that is placement-new'ed, and am refraining from adding custom deleters just for this (unless of course it is in fact unavoidable)

Comment: You can't call `delete` because, in the general case, it doesn't know how to free the underlying storage.  There is definitely some mileage in using `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter. I would look into that, in your position.

Comment: Actually, it seems one can pair placement new and delete https://godbolt.org/z/7bWbPzT6W  At least I wasn't able to find a compiler that produces bad code.  It is only when alignment enters into picture the trouble manifests.

Comment: Actually, you can't.  For example, placement `new` can be used with a stack-based variable as backing storage.  Try calling `delete` then.

Comment: of course, one can not use `delete` on stack!  In order to end object's life time destructor must be called one way or another. On stack, if the object was initialized with a placement new, since scope exit won't call the destructor, it needs to be called explicitly.  But in situations when `delete` applies, such as when the allocation was made with `new`, then `delete` also calls the destructor. I don't see why one should call the destructor separately here, just because it happens to be necessary to do so for stack.

Comment: At any rate, my real question on this thread is alignment mismatch btw new and delete. And why, even if the integer value of the alignment argument is the same as `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__ `, a plain `delete` without explicit alignment is at fault.